# Expected a value of type 'Object', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to execute an app which i was create at a couple of months, and now, i had this message when i try to execute them.

This is the complete tree error:
An exception ocurred.
"Error: Expected a value of type 'Object', but got one of type 'Null'
dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49      throw*
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 127:3       castError
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 742:12  cast
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 78:24                 as
packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 87:20                       get [_ignoredServiceScripts]
packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 163:28                      _initializeCore
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 155:31                      [_initializeCore]
packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 197:11                      initializeApp
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 193:44                      initializeApp
packages/firebase_core/src/firebase.dart 43:47                                    initializeApp
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
packages/firebase_core/src/firebase.dart 39:43                                    initializeApp
packages/ezprice/main.dart 25:18                                                  main
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
packages/ezprice/main.dart 23:18                                                  main$
web_entrypoint.dart 24:31                                                         
lib/ui_web/ui_web/initialization.dart 41:15                                       
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 156:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 840:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 869:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 641:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 715:7                                         callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:15

here has a print of the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ7D3.png)

And this is my code:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/components/app_theme.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/ingrediente/cadastrar_ingrediente.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/ingrediente/visualizar_ingredientes.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/ingrediente/remover_ingrediente.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/login/login.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/login/cadastrar_usuario.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/login/esqueceu_senha.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/login/nova_senha.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/receita/cadastrar_receita.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/receita/EdicaoReceita.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/receita/precificacao.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/receita/remover_receita.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/receita/visualizar_receitas.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/receita/infos_receita.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/configuracao.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/home.dart';
import 'package:ezprice/views/sobre.dart';


Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppTheme.theme,
      title: 'EzPrice',
      initialRoute: '/login',
      routes: {
        '/login': (context) => Login(),
        '/cadastrar': (context) => CadastrarUsuario(),
        '/esqueceu-senha': (context) => EsqueceuSenha(),
        '/esqueceu-senha/nova-senha': (context) => NovaSenha(),
        '/home': (context) => Home(),
        '/sobre': (context) => const Sobre(),
        '/ingrediente/cadastrar': (context) => CadastrarIngrediente(),
        '/ingrediente/visualizar': (context) => VisualizarIngredientes(),
        '/receita/cadastrar': (context) => CadastrarReceita(),
        '/receita/visualizar': (context) => VisualizarReceitas(),
        '/receita/precificacao': (context) => const Precificar(
              nome: '',
            ),
        '/configuracao': (context) => const Configurar(),
        '/receita/EdicaoReceita': (context) => EdicaoReceita(
              idReceita: '',
            ),
        '/receita/remover_receita': (context) => RemoverReceita(),
        '/ingrediente/remover_ingrediente': (context) => remover_ingrediente(),
        '/receita/infos_receita':(context) => Visualizar()
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

The error is always found on the line where we have initalizeApp.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions to set up your firebase configuration?

Comment: The error is coming from this call `await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,);`, so (as Randal also commented) you'll want to check whether you've [set up Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) correctly, and maybe run in a debugger to see what value `currentPlatform` has, and what happens in `iniitializeApp` with it.